# Make "Review" Clickable On Review Home Page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

On the individual review pages (Close, Suggested Edits, etc.), the word Review in the header is clickable, and takes you back to the Review home page.

> [image: clickable]

On the Review home page, the same word is not clickable. It would be nice to be able to click that to refresh the page, just like I can click on the Stackoverflow logo from any page to either get home, or refresh.

Some of the smaller queues come and go so fast it would be nice to be able to click in, edit, click out, and then click to refresh in the same location.

> [image: not clickable]

Comment: Am I missing something? It is clickable for me..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra On SO or Meta? On SO it is not for me.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: It appears that it is only clickable for users with access to the 10k tools (because you get Tools *and* Review up there). Users without only get Review and it is not clickable.

Comment: Yeah, I see: `<h1>Review</h1>`. No `<a>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clickable on all pages now.