# Make the review link on the Review homepage clickable again

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks

The "Review" link (upperleft) used to be clickable (hyperlinked). It provided a 1 click only way to easily refresh the review page. With the changes applied today, the hyperlink is no longer available. So it seems to me that this is like an undo of the feature enabled via [Make “Review” Clickable On Review Home Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167943/286501).

With this change, I don't think there is any other 1-click-only hyperlink available on the review home page anymore (and the review button upper-right in the toolbar requires 2 clicks to achieve the same result).

**Note**: if you have access to the `/tools` page on a site, you can see that that page has 2 clickable links, 1 for *Review*, and 1 for *Tools*. That's perfect, so just implement the same links on the `/review` page also (to make it consistent).

Comment: Was about to post something along these lines - in addition to that, I feel like the "Review" and "Tools" design should look the same, like they used to, because they are of similar importance.

Comment: Merci @Jenayah, please go ahead to post an extra question about that Review / Tools design (I fully agree on that too).

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322032/398063)

Comment: I'm normally a fan of having a canonical link in the header, but... There are no non-canonical links to the review dashboard, so this just seems like the hard way to avoid hitting F5

Comment: Not all keyboards have an F5, and some people might now have any hands on their keyboard when they want to reload the Review page, and if the queues are empty, they won't need to (and the standard position of F5 is really poor ergonomically), so keyboard-based reloads might be really slow.