# Bring the "moderator tools" button back next to the "Review" one, and make them look the same

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools

The Review page used to have the "Tools" button right next to the titular "Review" one, enabling >10k reppers (less on Beta sites) to easily switch between the two:

> [image: Former review page on Mi Yodeya]

Right now, after the new design that was released today, it just looks plain weird:

> [image: current review page design on Science Fiction and Fantasy with the below annotations]

- the "Review" button isn't clickable anymore ([another question has a feature-request on that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322031/398063));
- the Review "button" and the Tools button look like completely different stuff: one actually has a button design, the other is an unclickable plain word. Having them look the same seems logical since they are of similar roles and importance;
- but more than anything else, the Tools button got moved on the far right side of the page, above the "How to review" banner which, in all honesty, one looks at *one* time in their life and then mentally dismisses it. At least one user didn't see the new Tools button (chat transcript [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48413894#48413894), goes on for a dozen messages) but I'm guessing they're not the only one.

I'm guessing (hoping) the current Review page design is still "in development" (as the review "subpages" haven't changed yet), so the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is for it to have the twin buttons back together, and looking similar.

I imagine that change being part of the "New Design/Responsiveness" stuff, so there are probably reasons behind this layout (which I'd be curious to know about), but as it is now, it has its flaws.

Comment: Interesting...the Tools page still has the two side-by-side.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yep, that's what I meant by the review "subpages" having not changed (yet). Accessing the review history looks the same too, with the Main nReview linked and the current reviewed one at its side

Comment: IIRC, that link ended up there originally because review stole the spot in the top bar from /tools (well, review was *originally* part of the 10k tools). I kinda felt like most folks didn't see it - it always looked greyed out. Interested to see if traffic pics up now that there's a visibly-clickable *button* for it.

Comment: Funny, I just requested the same on our meta: https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/misplaced-tools-link-on-the-review-page

Comment: @Shog9 It's been two months. Have stats been collected on that? If so, do they seem to  reveal anything relevant, one way or another?

Comment: Nothing too dramatic, @Jenayah. [Noticeable spike the week this change was made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMcwj.png)... But pretty much immediately back to normal.

Comment: @Shog9 alright, thanks for that. Follow-up question, I guess that means the FR won't be a thing? :)

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem like much point